# Caesar cipher code modification

Tags: java, encryption

I'm working on converting a Caesar shift code I found online to suit my needs, adding different functionality and whatnot.

The only help I'd like to ask for is getting the code to work through the console directly from the user instead of opening up a file, via `Scanner` rather than `InputStream`. I tried modifying the code on my own but the only luck I have had so far is that it compiles and outputs:

```
Usage: java Caesar (-d | -e) key
```

but it doesn't let the user enter anything. I posted the original code below. Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated.
    import java.io.*;

```
public class ShiftCipher {

    private Reader in; // standard input stream for message

    private int key; // (en|de)cryption key

    // Caesar: constructor, opens standard input, passes key

    public ShiftCipher(int k) {
        // open file
        in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        key = k;
    }

    // (en|de)crypt: just feed in opposite parameters
    public void encrypt() {
        translate(key);
    }

    public void decrypt() {
        translate(-key);
    }

    // translate: input message, translate
    private void translate(int k) {
        char c;
        while ((byte) (c = getNextChar()) != -1) {

            if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                c = rotate(c, k);
            }
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }

    // getNextChar: fetches next char.
    public char getNextChar() {
        char ch = ' '; // = ’ ’ to keep compiler happy
        try {
            ch = (char) in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception reading character");
        }
        return ch;
    }

    // rotate: translate using rotation, version with table lookup
    public char rotate(char c, int key) { // c must be lowercase
        String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 26) {
            // extra +26 below because key might be negative
            if (c == s.charAt(i))
                return s.charAt((i + key + 26) % 26);
            i++;
        }
        return c;
    }

    // main: check command, (en|de)crypt, feed in key value
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Caesar (-d | -e) key");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        ShiftCipher cipher = new ShiftCipher(Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        if (args[0].equals("-e"))
            cipher.encrypt();

        else if (args[0].equals("-d")) {
            cipher.decrypt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Caesar (-d | -e) key");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A you running via Eclipse or some other IDE? If, so you'll need to enter the arguments to pass to the application, example "-e 2". I tried this and it seems to run.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2, it compiles but just won't let me get passed that stage, only once has it let me input something. It's so peculiar...

Comment: I have the same version of Eclipse. Have you gone into "Run Configurations" then the "Arguments" tab, and set "Program arguments" to "-e 2"?

Comment: @user2827137 Additional tip, hit <ctrl><shift>F to format your code, select all of it and hit tab to ident it more for SO. Otherwise, first paste the code and hit the `{}` button when editing the question or answer. Could you please answer Alvin?

Comment: @Alvin Bunk, I did exactly what you said, and typed in "hello" and got a ciphertext of "jgnnq". I didn't realize that I would have to add the program argument myself. I appreciate the help. What's the best way to have the user type in the command themselves into the console?

Comment: You can create a shell script or start the console (cmd.exe or /bin/bash) from "External Tool Configurations -> Porgram"). You'll have to configure the classpath correctly though.